# knockout js, using subscribe after a change using jquery.

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is there a way to activate the subscribe, when we change something using jquery ?

for example:

```
var MyModel = function (){
 var self = this;
 this.ImageUrl= ko.observable("Image.jgp");
}

var Model = new MyModel (); 
ko.applyBindings(Model);
Model.ImageUrl.subscribe(function (NewValue)
{
console.log(NewValue);
})

<img data-bind:"attr{src: ImageUrl}" id ="image1" src = "" alt= "new image"/>
```

and I am using jquery to change the src:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
$("#image1").attr("src","image2.jpg");
})
```

this is a little example, I am not sure if this is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr` binding is a one-way binding, so it does not react to changes to the element (does not handle any events).

Knockout does include two helper functions called `ko.dataFor` and `ko.contextFor` that can give you the current data/context given a DOM element.  Here are the docs that we have on it: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html.

So, basically, if you want to attach your event handler via jQuery, then you would want to use `ko.dataFor` to get your data and then update your `ImageUrl` observable directly.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gbruu/